# jquery multiple selectors with unique timeouts on keyup/keydown events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a function that auto-saves input entered into a few textboxs. I have 3 inputs in one selector($input), and a timer(typingTimer) that updates on keyup/paste and keydown. If after a keyup event the timer hasn't been reset after 3 seconds(doneTypingInterval), the element is sent to an autosave function that posts the elements name and value via ajax.

The issue I'm having is that if I type in an input (ie: #input-name), and a second later I type in another (ie: #input-shortName), the first input (#input-name) is never sent to the autosave function. Is there a good way to do this without creating a unique typingTimer and on events for each input? I tried it that way and it works, but I'm sure there has to be a better way.

```
  let typingTimer;
  const doneTypingInterval = 3000;
  const $input = $('#input-name, #input-shortName, #input-email');

  $input
    .on('keyup paste', function () {
      if($.fn.isAutoSaveOn()) {
        clearTimeout(typingTimer);
        typingTimer = setTimeout($.fn.autoSaving, doneTypingInterval, this);
      }
    })
    .on('keydown', function () {
      if($.fn.isAutoSaveOn()) {
        clearTimeout(typingTimer);
      }
    })
  ;


$.fn.autoSaving = function(e) {
    const autosave = $('#autosave')
    if(autosave.hasClass('active')) {
      autosave.html('<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;' + lang_saving);

      const element = $(e);
      const url = '/v3/api/orgs/' + orgId + '/update';
      const input = JSON.stringify({
        field: element.attr('name'),
        value: element.val()
      });

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: input,
        contentType: "application/json"
      })
      .done(function(response) {
        notify("Success", response, "bottom", "right", "ni ni-bell-55", "success", "animated fadeIn", "animated fadeOut");
      })
      .fail(function(response) {
          notify("Error", response, "bottom", "right", "ni ni-bell-55", "error", "animated fadeIn", "animated fadeOut");
      })
      .always(function() {
        $.fn.autoSaveOn();
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: I can't think of any way of doing this without using multiple timers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to keep timeouts from overlapping each other, you could give the input a auto save timestamp and just check if that has passed.

```
let auto_save_timer = null;
    
$('input.auto-save').on('keyup paste', function() {
  this.setAttribute('data-auto-save-timeout', (new Date()).getTime() + 3000); //set save time

  if (!auto_save_timer) {
    auto_save_timer = setInterval(function() {
      let $inputs = $('input[data-auto-save-timeout]');

      if ($inputs.length) {
         $inputs.each(function() {
           if ((new Date()).getTime() - this.attributes['data-auto-save-timeout'].value >= 0) {
             this.removeAttribute('data-auto-save-timeout');
             your_save_function(this);
          }
         });
       } else {
         clearInterval(auto_save_timer); //stops the timer
         auto_save_timer = null; //for checking if the timer is active,
                                 //clearInterval() doesn't make it false      
                                 //this prevents multiple timers from overlapping
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sjmdqhgu/

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much! Also, what is the 1000 for at the end of the setInterval function used for?

Comment: It's how often it checks to see if a timeout has passed.1000 ms is 1 second. You can make this whatever you want, but most humans will perceive one second as realtime.

Answer (score 1):

Still using multiple timers but at least you don't have to declare everyone of them.
Create a function template

```
const doneTypingInterval = 3000

registerInput('input-name')
registerInput('input-shortName')
registerInput('input-email')

function registerInput (id) {
  let typingTimer
  $(`#${id}`).on('keyup paste', function () {
    if ($.fn.isAutoSaveOn()) {
      clearTimeout(typingTimer)
      typingTimer = setTimeout($.fn.autoSaving, doneTypingInterval, this)
    }
  }).on('keydown', function () {
    if ($.fn.isAutoSaveOn()) {
      clearTimeout(typingTimer)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: I'll give this a try later today. Thanks!